# Extract Values from Rows in Excel using powershell

Tags: excel, extract, powershell-5.0

I am novice to powershell.
I have an excel sheet with certain inputs, My excel sheet looks like

```
[excel][1]

$filepath="Path to file.xlsx"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$objExcel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item("sheet1")
$tooluse=Read-Host "Please Enter the tool"

for($i=2;$i -lt 8;$i++)
 {
     $op=$Worksheet.Rows.Item($i).Columns.Item(1).Text
     if ( $op -eq $tooluse )
     {
         return $tooluse
     }
}
```

I want my powershell script to print for input "java" .
1.6 sun

Comment: You 'forgot' to give a clear definition of how you EXCEL file look like.

Comment: HI @Luuk thanks for your help i am trying to add my excel file but not able to edit my excel file.

Answer (score 0):

With an excel file name abc.xlsx like this:
[image]

The script:

```
$filepath="D:\Temp\abc.xlsx"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$objExcel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item("abc")
$tooluse=Read-Host "Please Enter the tool"

for($i=1;$i -lt 4;$i++)
 {
     for($j=1;$j -lt 4;$j++)
     {
           $op=$Worksheet.Rows.Item($i).Columns.Item($j).Text
           echo "$i , $j : $op"
     }
}
```

Produces the output:

```
PS D:\temp> .\test.ps1                                                                                                  Please Enter the tool:
1 , 1 : a
1 , 2 : b
1 , 3 : c
2 , 1 : 1
2 , 2 : 2
2 , 3 : 3
3 , 1 : een
3 , 2 : twee
3 , 3 : drie
PS D:\temp>
```

Please, I am novice in powershell, too, but this seems to be …..

Investing in learning a tool?